# How to find the maximum value of a random vector with a loop in R

Tags: r, function, loops, vector

I have created a 100 digit vector with random numbers and I have to find the minimum and maximum values in r without using min() or max() functions. I have to use conditional logic and comparison operators, so I managed to find this for the minimum:

```
findMin <- function(x) {
minX <- x[1] 
for (i in (seq_along(x[-1]) + 1)) { 
if(x[i] < minX) 
minX <- x[i] 
 }
minX
}
findMin(myVector) ##'myVector' is the name of the random number vector.
```

Would anyone have a solution for the max that is similar? When I tried to change it up to work with Max instead, I only got warnings. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

edit: Here's an adapted version of the code that did not work. It simply returns the 100th value in the vector. I also think that the seq_along function may be what is messing it up but after a couple hours of trying different variations, I was still as just as lost

```
findMax<- function(x) {
MaxX<- x[100]
for (i in (seq_along(x[100]) - 1))
if (x[i]> MaxX)
 MaxX<-x[i]
 }
  MaxX
  }
```

Comment: What exactly does your code for the max look like. Show us your code and we can help you fix it.

Comment: Just edited the post, sorry for not including that initially. That is just how I originally adapted it to try and get it to work but as I said above, it only returns the 100th digit.

Comment: To find the the max literally you only have to change your comparison from `<` to `>`.  You don't need to be making any of the other changes you made and I'm not understanding why you would have made those changes in the first place.

Comment: You are absolutely correct! I misunderstood the meaning of the brackets (I'm super new to this if you can't tell haha) and that's where everything went awry. Thanks a lot for pointing that out, I was driving myself crazy trying to figure out why it wouldn't work.